# NetworkManager is not changing /etc/resolv.conf after openvpn dns push

Tags: domain-name-system, openvpn, resolv.conf, networkmanager

I've got a problem which is "NetworkManager is not updating `/etc/resolv.conf` after openvpn connection with dns push configured".

Here's my openvpn server config: (*I've changed domain name to ABC.COM for security reason ;)*)

```
########################################
# Sample OpenVPN config file for
# 2.0-style multi-client udp server
#
# Adapted from http://openvpn.sourceforge.net/20notes.html
#
# tun-style tunnel

port 1194
dev tun

# Use "local" to set the source address on multi-homed hosts
#local [IP address]

# TLS parms
tls-server 
ca keys/ca.crt
cert keys/static.crt
key keys/static.key
dh keys/dh1024.pem
proto tcp-server

# Tell OpenVPN to be a multi-client udp server
mode server

# The server's virtual endpoints
ifconfig 10.8.0.1 10.8.0.2

# Pool of /30 subnets to be allocated to clients.
# When a client connects, an --ifconfig command
# will be automatically generated and pushed back to
# the client.
ifconfig-pool 10.8.0.4 10.8.0.255

# Push route to client to bind it to our local
# virtual endpoint.
push "route 10.8.0.1 255.255.255.255"

push "dhcp-option DNS 10.8.0.1"

# Push any routes the client needs to get in
# to the local network.
#push "route 192.168.0.0 255.255.255.0"

# Push DHCP options to Windows clients.
push "dhcp-option DOMAIN ABC.COM"
#push "dhcp-option DNS 192.168.0.1"
#push "dhcp-option WINS 192.168.0.1"

# Client should attempt reconnection on link
# failure.
keepalive 10 60

# Delete client instances after some period
# of inactivity.
inactive 600

# Route the --ifconfig pool range into the
# OpenVPN server.
route 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0

# The server doesn't need privileges
user openvpn
group openvpn

# Keep TUN devices and keys open across restarts.
persist-tun
persist-key

verb 4
```

As you can see it's basicaly sample config with little tuning.

Now..

On my machine (openvpn client), I can see that dns is ok:

```
{17:12}/etc/NetworkManager ➭ nslookup git.ABC.COM 10.8.0.1
Server:     10.8.0.1
Address:    10.8.0.1#53

Name:   git.ABC.COM
Address: 10.8.0.1

{17:18}/etc/NetworkManager ➭ nslookup ABC.COM 10.8.0.1   
Server:     10.8.0.1
Address:    10.8.0.1#53

Name:   ABC.COM
Address: 18X.XX.XX.71
```

openvpn logs on server side says (if I understand correctly) that DNS has been pushed:

```
openvpn[13257]: TCPv4_SERVER link remote: [AF_INET]83.30.135.214:37658
openvpn[13257]: 83.30.135.214:37658 TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]83.30.135.214:37658, sid=3251df51 915772f3
openvpn[13257]: 83.30.135.214:37658 VERIFY OK: depth=1, C=XX, ST=XX, L=XXX, O=XXX, OU=XXX, CN=XXX, name=XXX, emailAddress=mail@ABC.COM
openvpn[13257]: 83.30.135.214:37658 VERIFY OK: depth=0, C=XX, ST=XX, L=XXX, O=XXX, OU=XXX, CN=XXX, name=XXX, emailAddress=mail@ABC.COM
openvpn[13257]: 83.30.135.214:37658 Data Channel Encrypt: Cipher 'BF-CBC' initialized with 128 bit key
openvpn[13257]: 83.30.135.214:37658 Data Channel Encrypt: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
openvpn[13257]: 83.30.135.214:37658 Data Channel Decrypt: Cipher 'BF-CBC' initialized with 128 bit key
openvpn[13257]: 83.30.135.214:37658 Data Channel Decrypt: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
openvpn[13257]: 83.30.135.214:37658 Control Channel: TLSv1, cipher TLSv1/SSLv3 DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA, 1024 bit RSA
openvpn[13257]: 83.30.135.214:37658 [jacek] Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET]83.30.135.214:37658
openvpn[13257]: jacek/83.30.135.214:37658 MULTI_sva: pool returned IPv4=10.8.0.10, IPv6=(Not enabled)
openvpn[13257]: jacek/83.30.135.214:37658 MULTI: Learn: 10.8.0.10 -> jacek/83.30.135.214:37658
openvpn[13257]: jacek/83.30.135.214:37658 MULTI: primary virtual IP for jacek/83.30.135.214:37658: 10.8.0.10
openvpn[13257]: jacek/83.30.135.214:37658 PUSH: Received control message: 'PUSH_REQUEST'
openvpn[13257]: jacek/83.30.135.214:37658 send_push_reply(): safe_cap=940
openvpn[13257]: jacek/83.30.135.214:37658 SENT CONTROL [jacek]: 'PUSH_REPLY,route 10.8.0.1 255.255.255.255,dhcp-option DNS 10.8.0.1,dhcp-option DOMAIN ABC.COM,ping 10,ping-restart 60,ifconfig 10.8.0.10 10.8.0.9' (status=1)
```

openvp logs on my side:

```
Aug 05 17:13:55 localhost.localdomain openvpn[1198]: TCPv4_CLIENT link remote: [AF_INET]XXX.XX.37.71:1194
Aug 05 17:13:55 localhost.localdomain openvpn[1198]: TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]XXX.XX.37.71:1194, sid=89cc981c d57dd826
Aug 05 17:13:56 localhost.localdomain openvpn[1198]: VERIFY OK: depth=1, C=XX, ST=XX, L=XXX, O=XXX, OU=XXX, CN=XXX, name=XXX, emailAddress=mail@ABC.COM
Aug 05 17:13:56 localhost.localdomain openvpn[1198]: VERIFY OK: depth=0, C=XX, ST=XX, L=XXX, O=XXX, OU=XXX, CN=XXX, name=XXX, emailAddress=mail@ABC.COM
Aug 05 17:13:58 localhost.localdomain openvpn[1198]: Data Channel Encrypt: Cipher 'BF-CBC' initialized with 128 bit key
Aug 05 17:13:58 localhost.localdomain openvpn[1198]: Data Channel Encrypt: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Aug 05 17:13:58 localhost.localdomain openvpn[1198]: Data Channel Decrypt: Cipher 'BF-CBC' initialized with 128 bit key
Aug 05 17:13:58 localhost.localdomain openvpn[1198]: Data Channel Decrypt: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Aug 05 17:13:58 localhost.localdomain openvpn[1198]: Control Channel: TLSv1, cipher TLSv1/SSLv3 DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA, 1024 bit RSA
Aug 05 17:13:58 localhost.localdomain openvpn[1198]: [static] Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET]XXX.XX.37.71:1194
Aug 05 17:14:00 localhost.localdomain openvpn[1198]: SENT CONTROL [static]: 'PUSH_REQUEST' (status=1)
Aug 05 17:14:01 localhost.localdomain openvpn[1198]: PUSH: Received control message: 'PUSH_REPLY,route 10.8.0.1 255.255.255.255,dhcp-option DNS 10.8.0.1,dhcp-option DOMAIN ABC.COM,ping 10,ping-restart 60,ifconfig 10.8.0.10 10.8.0.9'
Aug 05 17:14:01 localhost.localdomain openvpn[1198]: OPTIONS IMPORT: timers and/or timeouts modified
Aug 05 17:14:01 localhost.localdomain openvpn[1198]: OPTIONS IMPORT: --ifconfig/up options modified
Aug 05 17:14:01 localhost.localdomain openvpn[1198]: OPTIONS IMPORT: route options modified
Aug 05 17:14:01 localhost.localdomain openvpn[1198]: OPTIONS IMPORT: --ip-win32 and/or --dhcp-option options modified
Aug 05 17:14:01 localhost.localdomain openvpn[1198]: ROUTE_GATEWAY 10.123.123.1/255.255.255.0 IFACE=wlan0 HWADDR=44:6d:57:32:81:2e
Aug 05 17:14:01 localhost.localdomain openvpn[1198]: TUN/TAP device tun0 opened
Aug 05 17:14:01 localhost.localdomain openvpn[1198]: TUN/TAP TX queue length set to 100
Aug 05 17:14:01 localhost.localdomain openvpn[1198]: do_ifconfig, tt->ipv6=0, tt->did_ifconfig_ipv6_setup=0
Aug 05 17:14:01 localhost.localdomain openvpn[1198]: /usr/sbin/ip link set dev tun0 up mtu 1500
Aug 05 17:14:01 localhost.localdomain openvpn[1198]: /usr/sbin/ip addr add dev tun0 local 10.8.0.10 peer 10.8.0.9
Aug 05 17:14:01 localhost.localdomain openvpn[1198]: /usr/sbin/ip route add 10.8.0.1/32 via 10.8.0.9
Aug 05 17:14:01 localhost.localdomain openvpn[1198]: Initialization Sequence Completed
```

It looks like everything's fine.

But. I checked `/var/log/messages` also... and I found that line:

```
Aug  5 17:14:01 localhost NetworkManager[761]: <warn> /sys/devices/virtual/net/tun0: couldn't determine device driver; ignoring...
```

`ip a` returns:

```
5: tun0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN qlen 100
    link/none 
    inet 10.8.0.10 peer 10.8.0.9/32 scope global tun0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

`route -n` returns:

```
# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.123.123.1    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
10.8.0.1        10.8.0.9        255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 tun0
10.8.0.9        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
10.123.123.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wlan0
```

So basically everything works, except the DNS being pushed... Oh! Right, and my `/etc/resolv.conf`:

```
# Generated by NetworkManager
domain home
search home
nameserver 10.123.123.1
```

Where's the issue?

(I have a response from Windows-user with openvpn client, that on his side DNS works fine, so it's an issue on my side.

Ok now I have another response (after I restarted openvpn service on server side) - it's not working.

I must say that it worked yesterday on my machine too.. so have I screwed up something on server? What could it be? )

**Edit:**
Okay, I've got another Windows-user response (the same user as before) - it's working now. So.. I guess it was caused by openvpn restart and some delays with it. I haven't done anything since then. So we're back onto my machine.

I also traced that that wierd `tun0` message appeared also yesterday, and yesterday it worked. Or maybe I added entry to `resolv.conf` by myself? I don't remember.. (damn it)

Comment: I have seen this happen on systems with selinux enabled and whose resolv.conf file had the wrong selinux security context. Running restorecon to restore the security context on that file resolved the issue. P.S.: it's resolv.conf, not resolve.conf

Comment: Put a particular attention to `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`: uncomment `dns=dnsmasq` and have `managed=true`. Also, you may be affected by [Bug #1294899 Import saved VPN connection has been Recently Broken](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager-openvpn/+bug/1294899) despite a reported "estblished" VPN connection. Check your VPN settings: Put the protocol name (`:tcp` or `:udp`) in the `Gateway` field. Check the advanced settings, especially `Port number` and `LZO compression`. Also check the logs. Finish with a [DNS leak test](https://ipleak.net/).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This works for me: http://www.softwarepassion.com/solving-dns-problems-with-openvpn-on-ubuntu-box/

The important step is adding following three lines of configuration into your **client** openvpn config file:

```
script-security 2
up /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
down /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
```

Also ensure the `resolvconf` package is installed on the client, because that `update-resolv-conf` script depends on it.

It works with openvpn client service or command to start it manually.

However, the Ubuntu Network Manager doesn't this. It's an issue so far: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openvpn/+bug/1211110

Comment: Don't forget to run openvpn with --script-security 2

Comment: Or also put `script-security 2` in your client openvpn config file.

Comment: I don't recommend using OpenVPN directly, without going through Network-Manager, or you may face [Bug #691723 OpenVPN Client Ignores DNS](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openvpn/+bug/691723) which has no solution. In my case, Network Manager overwritten resolvconf after the `up` script was launched... A dirty `# echo "nameserver 208.67.220.220" | /sbin/resolvconf -a "tun0.openvpn"` AFTER running openvpn can do the job... until it gets overwritten again. Again, don't use OpenVPN directly.

Comment: `up` command not found !!

Comment: @KrisWebDev: That is true, but using OpenVPN through NetworkManager allows users to disable (turn `Off`) the connection which admins may not desire.

Answer (score 12):

Works for me after disabling NetworkManager's own dnsmasq.

Edit `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`

```
 #dns=dnsmasq
```

and restart NetworkManager

```
sudo restart network-manager
```

Comment: I already had the change from Bruce Li in my client config.  Making this change as well fixed the issue [Ubuntu 15.10].

Comment: What kind of sorcery is this? What dnsmasq is doing?

Comment: This worked for me in different versions of Ubuntu. I don't really understand what dnsmasq does, but commenting out that line from NetworkManager.conf magically solves the issue for VPN connections as well as for Wi-Fi connections.

Comment: This worked for me running Linux Mint 18, although I had to restart my machine because sudo restart network-manager failed with an error. The accepted answer did not work for me.

Comment: on restarte command throwing error `restart: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused`

Comment: If not worked last command run these * sudo service networking restart 
* sudo service network-manager restart

Answer (score 10):

Finally works (with standard NetworkManager and OVPN plugin)

```
nmcli -p connection modify MY_VPN_CONNECTION ipv4.never-default no
nmcli -p connection modify MY_VPN_CONNECTION ipv4.ignore-auto-dns no
nmcli -p connection modify MY_VPN_CONNECTION ipv4.dns-priority -42
```

In this case once VPN connection is established, all DNS requests are directed to VPN-supplied DNS servers without any manipulations with dnsmasq, up/down/dispatch helper scripts.

Comment: this works, 10x

Comment: I found I only had to use the last line ```nmcli -p connection modify MY_VPN_CONNECTION ipv4.dns-priority -42```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to push DNS settings in OpenVPN. Like you have in your config, it is done in the server configuration with the following line:

`push "dhcp-option DNS 10.20.30.40"`

This works out of the gate for me using the Windows GUI, but it needs a bit of nudging for Linux systems. For connecting to my home network (using Fedora 18 at present), I used a script by gronke on GitHub (https://github.com/gronke/OpenVPN-linux-push) to automate the updating process.

To use these scripts, I added the following to my OpenVPN client file:

```
up /home/gadgeteering/tools/vpn/up.sh
down /home/gadgeteering/tools/vpn/down.sh
```

up.sh:

```
#! /bin/bash
DEV=$1

if [ ! -d /tmp/openvpn ]; then
mkdir /tmp/openvpn
fi
CACHE_NAMESERVER="/tmp/openvpn/$DEV.nameserver"
echo -n "" > $CACHE_NAMESERVER

dns=dns
for opt in ${!foreign_option_*}
do
eval "dns=\${$opt#dhcp-option DNS }"
if [[ $dns =~ [0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3} ]]; then
if [ ! -f /etc/resolv.conf.default ]; then
cp /etc/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf.default
fi

cat /etc/resolv.conf | grep -v ^# | grep -v ^nameserver > /tmp/resolv.conf
echo "nameserver $dns" >> /tmp/resolv.conf
echo $dns >> $CACHE_NAMESERVER
cat /etc/resolv.conf | grep -v ^# | grep -v "nameserver $dns" | grep nameserver >> /tmp/resolv.conf
mv /tmp/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf

fi
done
```

down.sh:

```
#! /bin/bash
DEV=$1
CACHE_NAMESERVER="/tmp/openvpn/$DEV.nameserver"
echo $CACHE_NAMESERVER

if [ -f $CACHE_NAMESERVER ]; then
for ns in `cat $CACHE_NAMESERVER`; do
echo "Removing $ns from /etc/resolv.conf"
cat /etc/resolv.conf | grep -v "nameserver $ns" > /tmp/resolv.conf
mv /tmp/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf

done
fi
```

Comment: why you need `dns=dns` ?

Comment: That would be a question for Gronke, I think it's a bit odd as well. Since writing my comment, I've moved on to using an adaptation of this script that doesn't use the 'dns' variable at all. I have not observed any change in behavior because of the omission.

Answer (score 1):

There is a possibility to make NetworkManager working by manually replacing `/etc/resolv.conf`. Beware that this is quite a hack and cannot be considered as a valid solution for every situation.

```
#!/bin/bash
case "$2" in
    vpn-up)
    tmp=$(mktemp)
    func=$(mktemp)
    echo 'ping -c 1 -w 1 -q $1 > /dev/null ;
          if [ 0 -eq $? ]; then echo $1; fi' > $func
    grep -v "^#" /etc/resolv.conf > $tmp
    grep -rl type=vpn /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections \
        | xargs -n 1 sed -rne 's|dns=||p' \
        | sed -re 's|;|\n|g' \
        | grep -v "^\s*$" \
        | xargs -n 1 bash $func \
        | sed -re "s|(.*)|nameserver \1|" \
        | cat - $tmp \
        > /etc/resolv.conf
    rm -f $tmp $func;;
    vpn-down) resolvconf -u;;
esac
```

This script should be placed under `/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d`; should be executable and owned by root. It reads all NetworkManager vpn configutations it can find and rewrites `/etc/resolv.conf` with accessible nameservers found there. It doesn't write `domain` and `search` lines; but it allows to forget about nasty NetworkManager bug.

I use Ubuntu 16.04, it works.

Answer (score 1):

im running on linux ubuntu 18.04 and i had the same issue. The scripts in up and down sections only works for me if i execute the openvpn script in the command line but in my case, i running the Openvpn with Network Manager GUI. To resolve the issue, i create a rule in udev system to execute an script that change my DNS nameservers and domain and search tags.

To accomplished the tasks i use the name "exa" to named the interface as an example. You sure use the name that you want; please take care of the name in all sections of the tasks, and replace in all parts.

1- first change the order of the "dns" word in /etc/nsswitch.conf for the line that start with hosts:

old:

```
hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] resolve [!UNAVAIL=return] dns myhostname
```

new:

```
hosts:          files mdns4_minimal dns [NOTFOUND=return] resolve [!UNAVAIL=return] myhostname
```

2- next, create a bash script in /usr/local/bin/add_dns.sh and put the privileges to full (777):

```
#!/bin/bash

sleep 5

mv /etc/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf.old
echo "nameserver 10.10.10.10" > /etc/resolv.conf
echo "nameserver 10.10.11.10" >> /etc/resolv.conf
echo "search domain.example.com" >> /etc/resolv.conf
echo "domain domain.example.com" >> /etc/resolv.conf
```

3- create a rule in udev, /etc/udev/rules.d/74-exa-vpn.rules:

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="net", ENV{INTERFACE}=="exa", RUN+="/usr/local/bin/add_dns.sh"
```

4- reload the udev config with:

```
$ udevadm control --reload
```

5- Go to the networkmanager GUI and next go to the config of the VPN profile. Next, go to the tab "identity" -> "Advanced": in the option "set virutal device type TUN and name", put the name "exa" and save all.

The good thing is when i disconnect the VPN, the networkmanager replace the file created by the udev script and replace for the original.

Answer (score 0):

OpenVPN is currently unable to push DNS settings. You will have to manually change /etc/resolv.conf to match your (secured) DNS server. I just run a BIND9 service on the same machine as my Access Server and point to that via tunnel. Use your local IP adress of that machine eg 192.168.1.110

Good luck!

Jasper

Comment: With answer from Bruce Li, the /etc/resolv.conf is automatically modified

Answer (score 0):

I have an OpenSUSE client that doesn't use `resolvconf`, nor `systemd-networkd`, but I was able to modify [the common `update-resolv-conf` script](https://github.com/masterkorp/openvpn-update-resolv-conf) to work with NetworkManager's `nmcli` command:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#
# Parses DHCP options from openvpn to update resolv.conf
# To use set as 'up' and 'down' script in your openvpn *.conf:
# up /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
# down /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
#
# Example envs set from openvpn:
# foreign_option_1='dhcp-option DNS 193.43.27.132'
# foreign_option_2='dhcp-option DNS 193.43.27.133'
# foreign_option_3='dhcp-option DOMAIN be.bnc.ch'
# foreign_option_4='dhcp-option DOMAIN-SEARCH bnc.local'

case $script_type in

up)
    for optionname in ${!foreign_option_*} ; do
        option="${!optionname}"
        echo $option
        part1=$(echo "$option" | cut -d " " -f 1)
        if [ "$part1" == "dhcp-option" ] ; then
            part2=$(echo "$option" | cut -d " " -f 2)
            part3=$(echo "$option" | cut -d " " -f 3)
            if [ "$part2" == "DNS" ] ; then
                IF_DNS_NAMESERVERS="$IF_DNS_NAMESERVERS $part3"
            fi
            if [[ "$part2" == "DOMAIN" || "$part2" == "DOMAIN-SEARCH" ]] ; then
                IF_DNS_SEARCH="$IF_DNS_SEARCH $part3"
            fi
        fi
    done
    if [ -n "$IF_DNS_SEARCH" ]; then
        nmcli connection modify "${dev}" ipv4.dns-search "$IF_DNS_SEARCH"
    fi
    if [ -n "$IF_DNS_NAMESERVERS" ]; then
        nmcli connection modify "${dev}" ipv4.dns "$IF_DNS_NAMESERVERS"
    fi
    nmcli connection up "${dev}" # Force NM to reevaluate the properties
    ;;
esac

# Workaround / jm@epiclabs.io 
# force exit with no errors. Due to an apparent conflict with the Network Manager
# $RESOLVCONF sometimes exits with error code 6 even though it has performed the
# action correctly and OpenVPN shuts down.
exit 0
```

It doesn't have a `down` handler because NetworkManager automatically removes the `nameserver` and `search` (DNS search) parameters on the termination of the connection.