# OpenVPN Configuration Setup

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, openvpn

I have a CentOS 6.64bit machine that I installed OpenVPN on.

I want to have OpenVPN setup internally as a VPN to replace QuickVPN(it's horrible, fragile and randomly will work on Windows 8.x and not even supported by Cisco anymore).

I can't access the internet when on the OpenVPN connection. I have the following iptable ruleset in place:

```
iptables -t -nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.2.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

I am connecting as 192.168.2.6

Also, is there a way to set OpenVPN to use my DHCP/DNS server on 192.168.2.10?

SERVER.CONF:

```
 cat /etc/openvpn/server.conf
port 1194 #- port
proto udp #- protocol
dev tun
tun-mtu 1500
tun-mtu-extra 32
mssfix 1450
reneg-sec 0
ca /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/2.0/keys/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/2.0/keys/server.crt
key /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/2.0/keys/server.key
dh /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/2.0/keys/dh1024.pem
plugin /usr/share/openvpn/plugin/lib/openvpn-auth-pam.so /etc/pam.d/login #- Comment this line if you are using FreeRADIUS
#plugin /etc/openvpn/radiusplugin.so /etc/openvpn/radiusplugin.cnf #- Uncomment this line if you are using FreeRADIUS
client-cert-not-required
username-as-common-name
server 192.168.2.0 255.255.255.0
push "redirect-gateway def1"
push "dhcp-option DNS 192.168.2.10"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
push "route 0.0.0.0 255.255.255.255 192.168.2.254"
keepalive 5 30
comp-lzo
persist-key
persist-tun
status 1194.log
verb 3
```

Comment: You need to setup a bridge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Networking**

It looks like you're assigning your clients to the same subnet as your main network. When you use `tun` as your device, your server gives each client a /30 block.

I think some of your numbering choices were defined by the way you would set up an OpenVPN server with a `tap` device (bridge) instead of a `tun`. I've experienced better performance using `tun` devices than `tap` (bridge) devices in my experience for the home network, though I don't have any numbers to back up that feeling.

If you were to change your `server` directive to `server 192.168.3.0 255.255.255.0`, then your server would have an IP of 192.168.3.1/24 in addition to its normal 192.168.2._ address. I'm not sure on why it insists on the .1. It hasn't done me any harm, so I haven't pursued changing it. When your client machine connects, it would then be given an address like 192.168.3.6.

You don't need to specify the gateway for the route you're pushing. Saying `push "route 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0` should do it. If you're always going to be re-directing a clients traffic through the server, this will be redundant.

Make sure that routing is enabled on your machine:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

To make this change persistent after a restart, open `/etc/sysctl.conf` for editing and set the value of `net.ipv4.ip_forward` to **1**.

When client machines attempt to speak to the internet and beyond, they will need to go through the FORWARD chain in `iptables`. You can use this to tweak exactly how much access you want VPN clients to have to your network or the internet.

**DNS**

As far as DNS goes, I would only push the one DNS server to remote clients once you've made sure that they can connect. This should be read by Windows clients right off the bat, but for Linux it needs an adjustment to the configuration file plus a few supporting scripts.

Grabbing my response to another similar topic on OpenVPN and DNS on Linux ([NetworkManager is not changing /etc/resolv.conf after openvpn dns push](https://serverfault.com/questions/528773/networkmanager-is-not-changing-etc-resolve-conf-after-openvpn-dns-push/563226#563226)):

For connecting to my home network (using Fedora 18 at the time), I used a script by gronke on GitHub (https://github.com/gronke/OpenVPN-linux-push) to automate the updating process.

To use these scripts, I added the following to my OpenVPN client file:

```
up /home/gadgeteering/tools/vpn/up.sh
down /home/gadgeteering/tools/vpn/down.sh
```

Make sure that the client has permission to run these scripts using `chmod`.

up.sh:

```
#! /bin/bash
DEV=$1

if [ ! -d /tmp/openvpn ]; then
mkdir /tmp/openvpn
fi
CACHE_NAMESERVER="/tmp/openvpn/$DEV.nameserver"
echo -n "" > $CACHE_NAMESERVER

dns=dns
for opt in ${!foreign_option_*}
do
eval "dns=\${$opt#dhcp-option DNS }"
if [[ $dns =~ [0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3} ]]; then
if [ ! -f /etc/resolv.conf.default ]; then
cp /etc/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf.default
fi

cat /etc/resolv.conf | grep -v ^# | grep -v ^nameserver > /tmp/resolv.conf
echo "nameserver $dns" >> /tmp/resolv.conf
echo $dns >> $CACHE_NAMESERVER
cat /etc/resolv.conf | grep -v ^# | grep -v "nameserver $dns" | grep nameserver >> /tmp/resolv.conf
mv /tmp/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf

fi
done
```

down.sh:

```
#! /bin/bash
DEV=$1
CACHE_NAMESERVER="/tmp/openvpn/$DEV.nameserver"
echo $CACHE_NAMESERVER

if [ -f $CACHE_NAMESERVER ]; then
for ns in `cat $CACHE_NAMESERVER`; do
echo "Removing $ns from /etc/resolv.conf"
cat /etc/resolv.conf | grep -v "nameserver $ns" > /tmp/resolv.conf
mv /tmp/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf

done
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a bridge, plus with a bridge you would need tap support.

Try setting this to match your network instead of 0.0.0.0

e.g. push "route 192.168.0.0 255.255.255.0"

and check your iptables rules, I use this (192.168.150.0 is my VPN subnet)

iptables -I INPUT 1 -p udp --dport 1194 -j ACCEPT

iptables -I FORWARD 1 --source 192.168.150.0/24 -j ACCEPT